# force https on a subfolder not working with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I manually type https://www.domain.com.br/app/, the page loads correctly. But when I add a .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} app 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com.br/app/$1 [R,L]
```

The browser say my domain is not working, and show this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you create address  https://domain.com.br/app/app/ and this can be catched on another place and return to begining. rule alone should be

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Another thing is make decission based on protovol, not on port. Complete code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app(/.*)?
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```